# Website is incomplete and white

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We have backuped and than cancelled the folder "wp-content" from the program Viper FTP Lite. When we uploaded the "wp-content" (the backup one) folder to the website it get a white page. Than we have renamed the folder "plugins" into "plugins_deactivate" (to be able to see again the plugins), and we were able to see half of the site, and than we have updated all the plugins and than re-activated them, but we still see only the menu and the logo. To resolve this problem we have checked all plugins folders to verify what crash our website by renamed folder-by-folder and check everytime but still doesn't work. We have also restored the file "wp-config.php" with no fortune.

Comment: since it's a wordpress website did you check if `/wp-admin` worked?. One of the problems could also be that the site-url is incorrect. Do check your DB on the things like your site-url and etc.

Comment: Check the server's error logs and try a complete restore, not just the one folder.

Comment: we have change the answer.

Answer (score -1):

To determine PHP fatal errors (which are usually disabled on web servers and causing white/blank screens / incomplete parts), put this into beginning (after php opening tag) of index.php. Then reload the web page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","1");
```

Then of course delete this after problems are resolved :)